# Group the list data by id with nested lists of objects in Java Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, collections, db2, java-stream

This is my table data.

PRODUCTS

```
    id                  eid             item        stage       score       url             product
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    1933337     d96f32c4decc7d0         host        Server      0.3908    "https://"        "Real"
    2933337     96f32c4decc7d0          local       Server      0.3908    "https://"        "Virtual"
    1933337     d96f32c4decc7d0         host        Server      0.3908    "https://"        "Real"
    2933337     96f32c4decc7d0          local       Server      0.3908    "https://"        "Virtual"
```

I want to aggregate the data by id, each with nested items list & each item with a nested queued list in java.

Expected Output:

```
    [
        {
            "id": 1933337,
            "eid": d96f32c4decc7d0,
            "items": [
                    {
                        "item": "host",
                        "stage": "Server",
                        "score" : 0.3908,
                        "queued" : [
                                {
                                    "url": "https://",
                                    "product": "Virtual"
                                },
                                {
                                    "url": "https://",
                                    "product": "Real"
                                }                   
                        ]
                    }
            ]
        },
        {
            "id": 2933337,
            "eid": 96f32c4decc7d0,
            "items": [
                    {
                        "item": "local",
                        "stage": "Server",
                        "score" : 0.3908,
                        "queued" : [
                                {
                                    "url": "https://",
                                    "product": "Virtual"
                                },
                                {
                                    "url": "https://",
                                    "product": "Real"
                                }                   
                        ]
                    }
            ]
        }
    ]
```

I have tried stream API but its overriding the grouped data & every list is with same data.

I have tried DB2 query:

```
    DECLARE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE prod_json_objcts AS ( 
    WITH BASE AS ( 
    select id, item, 
      JSON_OBJECT('item' value item, 
                   'itemScore' value itemScore,
                   'stage' value stage,
                   'reco' VALUE JSON_OBJECT('product' value product,
                                            'url' value url ,
                                            'score' value score 
                                            FORMAT JSON ) 
                    FORMAT JSON ABSENT ON NULL  
                   RETURNING VARCHAR(200) FORMAT JSON) ITEM_JSON  
    FROM PROD_T  ) 
     SELECT JSON_OBJECT ( KEY 'id' VALUE ID , 
                KEY 'itens' VALUE 
                       JSON_ARRAY ( LISTAGG( ITEM_JSON , ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY ITEM) FORMAT JSON ) 
                FORMAT JSON ) json_objects 
     FROM BASE GROUP BY ID 
    ) WITH DATA 
    
    SELECT JSON_ARRAY (select json_objects FROM session.prod_json_objcts format json) FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
```

Produces the json array :

```
    [{"id":2078012,
      "itens":[
          {"item":"build",
           "score":-0.2585,
           "stage":"",
           "reco":{"product":"Notification",
                   "url":"https:\/\/"}}, 
          {"item":"cos",
           "score":-0.1334,
           "stage":"",
           "reco":{"product":"Language",
                   "url":"https:\/\/"}}
        ]
     },
     {"id":2100000,
      "itens":[
          {"item":"alpha",
           "score":-0.1334,
           "stage":"",
           "queued":{"product":"Letter",
                   "url":"https:\/\/"}
            }, 
            {"item":"beta",
             "score":-0.2585,
             "stage":"",
             "queued":{"product":"anouncement",
                     "url":"https:\/\/"}
        ]
     }
    ]
```

I want queued object as an array

SPRING BOOT:

```
    private List<ProductDto> parseData(List<Product> productList) {
        Map<Long, List<Product>> mapById =
                productList.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Product::getId));

        List<ProductDto> productDtos= new ArrayList<>();
        for (Map.Entry<Long,List<Product>> entry : mapById.entrySet()) {
            Map<String, List<Product>> mapByItem =
                    entry.getValue().stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Product::getItem));
            List<Items> itemList = new ArrayList<>();
            for (Map.Entry<String,List<Product>> entryUc : mapByItem.entrySet()) {

                List<Queued> qList = entryUc.getValue().stream()
                        .map(Product::getQ)
                        .collect(Collectors.toList());

                itemList .add(new Items(entryUc.getValue().get(0).getItem(),
                        entryUc.getValue().get(0).getScore(),
                        entryUc.getValue().get(0).getStage(),
                        qList ));
            }

            productDtos.add(new ProductDto(
                    entry.getKey(),
                    useCasesList));
        }
        return productDtos;
    }
```

Its also not working.
In map, I am getting same object multiple times.
Its overriding the entris or adding duplicate data, don't know the exact reason.

Comment: What is the output/structrue of that line? Map<Long, List<Product>> mapById =
                productList.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Product::getId))

Comment: You have put a lot of effort into trying to explain the situation, we respect that but please do not post such lengthy question on SO, try to keep things simple and short as possible.